# CSS reference not updating the referenced object

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I am using a React app here.

```
.menu[data-active-index="0"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -25%;
}
```

This code is supposed to set the background position of the `menu-background-pattern`.
When i console.log(menu), i receive:

```
<div id="menu" data-active-index="0"></div>
```

so there is a match. yet, the css code is not executed on the menu-background-pattern. whats wrong here?

App.js:

```
import React from "react";

export default function listWithBackgroundAnimation() {
    const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
        .forEach((item, index) => {
            item.onmouseover = () => {
                menu.dataset.activeIndex = index; // numerates elements top to bottom 0 to (length-1)
                console.log(menu) // <div id="menu" data-active-index="2"></div>
                console.log(menu.dataset)
            }
        })
        
    return (
        <div className="menu" >
            <div className="menu-items">
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
            </div>
                <div className="menu-background-pattern">
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

index.css:

```
.menu { 
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-items {
  margin-left: clamp(4rem, 20vw, 48rem);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

/*
  Opacity of the links
*/
.menu-items:hover > .menu-item{
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.menu-items:hover > .menu-item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*
  Motion of background-pattern on hover
*/
.menu-items:hover ~ .menu-background-pattern {
  background-size: 11vmin 11vmin;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.menu-item {
  color: white;
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 8vw, 8rem);
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', serif;

  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: clamp(0.25rem, 0.5vw, 1rem) 0rem;

  transition: opacity 400ms ease;
}

.menu-background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  background-image: radial-gradient(
    rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 9%,
    transparent 9%
    );
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: 12vmin 12vmin;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

    transition: opacity 800ms ease,
      background-size 800ms ease;
}

#menu[data-active-index="0"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -25%;
}

#menu[data-active-index="1"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -50%;
}

#menu[data-active-index="2"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -75%;
}

#menu[data-active-index="3"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -100%;
}
```

Comment: we need to see your background definition

Comment: you are using `.menu` which is a selector for classes but you specified menu as `id`. Try `#menu[data-active-index="0"]` instead.

Comment: As far as I can see here is you are using class notation for applying css, it should be 'id' notation.

Here in the above e.g

> .menu[data-active-index="0"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -25%;
}


Here is menu is an id

So we can use

```
#menu[data-active-index="0"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -25%;
}
```

Comment: I have added the complete css and js file for Temani Afif.

Although upvoted, Laszlo's suggestion sadly does nothing for me. 
I also would say its possible that its a bug, since the console.log() statements are not regularly executed, for example it will stop logging if i hit refresh in browser. 

keep in mind its a react app, so this might be the reason

Comment: if anyone is interested, here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUeCNvYY_x4&ab_channel=Hyperplexed
@TemaniAfif